# How to present Google Place Picker UI Widget on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3

I have added the below code from google documentation but it doesn't load placePicker

If i add a button and add the same code to an IBAction it works perfectly.

Can someone help me understand what is the problem?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)
    placePicker.delegate = self
    present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: add present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) in mainqueue as DispatchQueue.Main.Async {present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)}